# Reset Randomize/random number generation seed in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

So I am creating an application where the user can either input a seed, or a seed is randomly generated for them. Then, this seed is passed to the `Randomize` function which calls `Rnd` several times. The intention is that if the same seed is used - either if it's generated randomly, or if it's entered by the user - then the output list of random numbers should be the same.

The problem I ran into is that when I randomly generate the seed, this will throw off the random number generator - and I'm not sure how to reset it entirely. My code looks like this:

```
If UserEnteredSeed() Then
    Randomize(userSeed)
Else
    Randomize()
    userSeed = Rnd() + Rnd() ' This part is just a placeholder - but the Rnd function is called several times
End If

Randomize(userSeed)

Debug.Print(Rnd().ToString())
```

My problem is that when the `Else` clause is reached, the use of the `Rnd` function will (to my understanding) traverse the list of random numbers, and then when the next `Randomize` is called with `userSeed`, the list changes but the position within the list does not. This will change the output when the `Else` clause is not reached and `Rnd` is not called several times.

My question is, can I completely reset the random number generation so that regardless of whether the `userSeed` number is entered or generated, the same `userSeed` produces the same random number as output? Or if not, how can I effectively create the same intended behaviour?

Comment: Are you really using VB.Net? (the `ToString()` implies you are!)  If so, why are you using the old Randomize()/Rnd() functions? Those are just for backwards compatibility and/or converted programs. Use the newer [Random()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0) class instead...

Comment: As suggested, you should be using the `Random` class. Just create a new instance whenever you need a new seed. The constructor will take a number for a specific seed or no argument to use the current time as a seed.

Comment: @JackBashford, you don't need to ask something that you can easily test for yourself.

Comment: @user17922293 my bad, was on a different machine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[Calling Rnd() with a negative argument before calling Randomize() with a numeric argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbmath.randomize?view=net-6.0) will repeat sequences of random numbers.

Comment: Would the negative argument depend on the position I am within the sequence? Or where in the sequence would it place me (if you know)? I just tested it and it does work, but it places me arbitrarily in the sequence (so my problem is fixed, just curious about what exactly is happening now).